# Parsing JSON using JToken.Parse - help me convert one line of code from C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, json

I am having trouble getting the same result in VB.Net from example in C# found on [this page](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ParseJsonAny.htm):

The C# example returns "Object", but in VB.Net I get "1" instead. Any ideas how to get same result?

C#:

```
JToken t1 = JToken.Parse("{}");
Console.WriteLine(t1.Type);
// Object
```

VB:

```
Dim t1 As JToken = JToken.Parse("{}")
Console.WriteLine(t1.Type)
// 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

j1.Type is actually an enum (JTokenType) and its value is `1`, So they are the same

```
public enum JTokenType
{
    // Summary:
    //     No token type has been set.
    None = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A JSON object.
    Object = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A JSON array.
    Array = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A JSON constructor.
    Constructor = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A JSON object property.
    Property = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A comment.
    Comment = 5,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     An integer value.
    Integer = 6,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A float value.
    Float = 7,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A string value.
    String = 8,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A boolean value.
    Boolean = 9,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A null value.
    Null = 10,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     An undefined value.
    Undefined = 11,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A date value.
    Date = 12,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A raw JSON value.
    Raw = 13,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A collection of bytes value.
    Bytes = 14,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A Guid value.
    Guid = 15,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A Uri value.
    Uri = 16,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     A TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan = 17,
}
```

try this:

```
JToken t1 = JToken.Parse("{}");
Console.WriteLine((int)t1.Type);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me in VB.Net:

```
Dim t1 As JToken = JToken.Parse("{}")
Console.WriteLine((t1.Type).ToString)
//Object
```